# Classification using Multiple CSV files with filename as label

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science

I am dealing with Sensor Data which has numerical observations for different variables. I want to classify them into three labels A, B, C.

But, here the situation is different.

I have 30 Instances for training (or labelled data) and 20 instances for testing (unlabelled data).

Now, these instances are time series recordings for variables and parameters recorded by the sensor. Each instance (or a single observation) is a CSV as shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXqYW.png) file.

The name of the CSV file is the label, this label I need to classify. So, I have 30 CSV files or instances (or thirty labels) and 20 instances or CSV files for testing.

All the CSV files have same data structure. there is no label in any file, since they are itself a single observation(of shape 5000, 12) and represent a single observation altogether, and the filename for example classA.csv , where Class A is target variable

I want to figure out, how can I put these data (each observation (or class) of training data is a csv file and each file contains 5000 observations).

Please Suggest.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have any idea of nature of your data? Machine learning algorithms can tell one category from another, but it can choose for it some random data difference and it will bring you nowhere. You can add to each file 'label' column and place name of this file here. When concatenate all files and feed all data to xgboost. May be you'll get something useful, may be not. But you can try.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading this link to understand Python's CSV interface:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Your basic steps will be:

1. Point Python to the directory where your data is stored
2. Iterate through the files in this directory
3. For each file:
   Use Python's CSV interface to pull out the data and place it in your data structure. When you parse the CSV, you will have an array of rows you can iterate through to pull data. I recommend looking under the "short usage example" to see how you can access the data.

Comment: I am was not able to read into different files in pandas from this link.